# How to setup SFML without an IDE

Tags: c++, mingw, sfml

I really like SFML, and I would really like to use it with my preferred workflow, which means compiling my code directly in to the compiler via cmd. But I can't find any documentation that shows how to do this.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to build the library from the command line?  Or is it already built and you just want to use it with your application and compile that from the command line.

Comment: _@Lucas Davis_ Elaborate what specific problems you're stuck with.

Comment: Yes, the library is already built and I would like to use it with my project. And my problem is that there is no documentation that tells how. Am I just being a wuss with this whole thing and it's obvious what to do? If so, I'll be heading out.